# Changing CSS variables based on JavaScript events

Tags: facebook-apps

We have a Facebook app [here](https://www.facebook.com/MyPuzzler/app_142974305841145) which has three boxes with three buttons.  Each button, when clicked, should change state once an event (successfully) happens.  The buttons are almost all working (a few minor bugs) but they have been done a rather long-winded and inefficient way.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to link events (i.e. page 'liked', personal information submitted, page 'shared') with the state of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and the `.trigger()` function to fire off events. Then you can use `.bind()` to listen to the events and do something. For example, when the user logs in, you can trigger a `user_logged_in_event`, and bind to it. In the function, you can then use JS to change the login button to logout...